# Magento 2 tabs - change programmatically

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, tabs

I'm wondering how to exactly change tab (core mage/tabs widget) programmatically. Docs say that I can use both activate and enable functions for that: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_tabs.html

Unfortunately, no one is recognized.

Tabs are initialized as follows:

```
var tabs = $('.tabs');
tabs.tabs({
    openedState: 'active-tab'
});
```

Initialization and other base things work fine. The issue occurs when I would like to change tab programmatically:

```
tabs.activate('3'); // Uncaught TypeError: tabs.activate is not a function
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How are you adding your JS? e.g via XML or Require? If you're using require what dependencies have you added?

Comment: JS is added by data-mage-init attribute in phtml file. This is my dependencies in define/require block: **define([ 'jquery', 'matchMedia', tabs'], function ($, mediaCheck, tabs) { .. });**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/web/js/process-reviews.js:40` they are used like this:

```
$('.selector').tabs('activate', index);
```

Comment: Hey, @BenCrook thanks for your response! I missed it. This time code goes further without any errors, unfortunately still nothing happen with tabs. I use debugger to check how browser interpreted this code: **tabs.tabs('activate' 114);** - just go ahead, as if nothing was inside there.

Comment: Try adding a comma after `'activate'`. If that still doesn't work to test the methods are working try `$('.selector').tabs('destroy')`. That should fully destroy the tabs.

Comment: I have changed initialization method and finally, your approach starts working :) thanks!

Comment: thank you. working here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.product.data.items').tabs('activate', index);
```

index starting from 0

also you can check index by below code

```
$('.product.data.items [data-role="content"]').each(function (index) { 
     alert(this.id+index);
})
```