# Review form in custom template not working Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, template, review, product-review

I have created a custom template for the product page based on the attribute value.

in my template i used below code to display the review section.

```
<?php  echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/view/review.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

with this code, i can see the link '**Be the first to review the product**'.

But after clicking the link, the review form tab is not expanding. Can anyone help me on this please?

sometimes in console i get this error,

> Uncaught Error: no such method 'activate' for tabs widget instance

Please check this n share your ideas.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: you tried this code --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195130/85907

Comment: Yes @mohit, but no luck

Comment: After code you run all command with clear var/cache and var/view_process???

Comment: Hi, why didn't you moved/edited the already existing review template(which contains the "Be the first to review the product/rating stars") ?

Comment: I have a requirement to load separate product page based the product attribute, loaded the separate template for it.

Comment: @jafarpinjar have you resolve this issue?

Comment: @HafizArslan, No temporarily i resolved it.

Comment: how, can u share the solution please

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to layout XML of your extension :

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submitReviewButton" xsi:type="string">.review .action.submit</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
            <block class="VENDOR\EXTENSION\Block\Order\Products" name="review_products" template="VENDOR_EXTENSION::proreview.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews.tab" as="reviews" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                        <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Now add your review.phtml code in to your phtml so it will work.

Happy coding.

Comment: hi @Mayur, can you explain briefly. its not working in default detail page also